# How to take a string, manipulate it, then instantiate that class in a macro?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

My goal is to do something like (and yes, this uses whitebox macros)

```
def apply_impl(c: Context)(str: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Any] = {
  import c.universe._
  val Literal(Constant(_str: String)) = str.tree
  val _str2 = getClassFromString(_str)
  c.Expr(q"new $_str")
}
```

The issue is that this is trating $_str as a string literal, not as a type. I know I'm probably missing something obvious...

Comment: FWIW I did solve this using showRaw in the repl and just constructing the term myself, but quasiquotes are far more elegant!

Comment: Can't check at the moment but I think `q"new ${ TypeName(_str) }"` should work.

Comment: Did you try `c.Expr(q"new ${tq"_str"}")` ?